# Grails Domain Class String List Not Persisting

Tags: java, grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

This is in grails 2.5.6 code. I have a domain class that uses inheritance. One of the subclasses contains a list of strings stored in the variable `values`. When calling `.save()`, the domain class itself saves correctly with the right inheritance behavior, but the values do not get saved. Here is my domain classes:

```
abstract class Condition implements ICondition, IMarshaler {
    String field;
    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false;
    }
    ...
}

class ListCondition extends Condition {
    static hasMany = [values: String];
    List<String> values;
    ...
}
```

Attempting to save a new list condition and the getting it again from the database shows that there is no values.

```
ListCondition condition = new ListCondition(field: 'someField', values: ['test', 'otherTest'])
condition.save()
println ListCondition.getAll()[0].values.size() // Prints 0
```

Comment: try condition.save(failOnError: true) which will give you some stacktrace if there's an error

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon a similar issue. Try `condition.save(flush: true)` or even better try running your persistence-logic inside a transaction. This seems to make the difference and is considered best-practice anyways.